# Bash command for regular expression substitution

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, regex, pipe

What bash command can be used for regex substitution on a pipe?

```
     cat foo.txt | someprogram
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want

```
sed 's/exp1/exp2/g' foo.txt > foo2.txt
```

Read more at [Sed tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), [Another tutorial](http://www.panix.com/~elflord/unix/sed.html), and [A small tutorial at Linux HOWTOs](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/sed_tutorial.htm)

Comment: sed isn't just a program, it's a way of life.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [perl one liners](http://sial.org/howto/perl/one-liner/) if you find you want more regular expression features than sed provides.  See this [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) for a comparison.  nik's example would look like:

```
perl -ple 's/exp1/exp2/g' foo > foo2.txt
```

Comment: I recently discovered perl -pe, and it's great to have a much more powerful regex engine available :)

Answer (score 1):

The program you are looking for is sed.